# how to push data into multidimensional array?

Tags: php

I have this multidimensional array in php:

```
$products = array(array(
                    "name" => "Hannah",
                    "id" => "eg01",
                    "price" => 120
                ),
                array(
                    "name" => "Natasha",
                    "id" => "eg02",
                    "price" => 125
                ));
```

How do I push new data in the array and save it?

I tried this code:
array_push($products, $name, $id, $price);

but it only replaces the new one every time I click the push button.
I wanted it to be saved every time i push.

Answer (score 1):

Either you can use **array_push()** method for inserting records in an array or we can append data like this

```
$products[] = ['key'=>'value'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array is made of sub arrays with named keys, you need to construct your inner array first.

```
array_push($products,array('name'=>$name,'id'=>$id,'price'=>$price));
```

or for verbosity

```
$item = array(
  'name'  => $name,
  'id'    => $id,
  'price' => $price
);
array_push( $products, $item );
```

you may also see this syntax

```
$products[] = array('name'=>$name,'id'=>$id,'price'=>$price);
```

in which you can optionally specify a key if needed between the `[]` notation